# Loop through URLs, apply BeautifulSoup, save files named after tuple elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tuples

This post contains several problems. Thank you for taking a look.

I have a dataframe containing columns 'URL,' 'CIK' and 'date.' The URLs are 10-ks from the EDGAR website -- CIKs are unique ID's for every filing entity, in case you were wondering. A portion of this dataframe can be found as csv [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4GKNSEDe65tUXpsdjIyZ1pFQXM/view?usp=sharing)

I would like to loop through each URL, apply BeautifulSoup, and save each to a unique text file named after the CIK and date.

My code so far:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import os

#x is a dataframe including columns 'url', 'cik' and 'date'
#convert x to tuple

subset = x[['url', 'cik', 'date']]
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]

os.chdir("C:/10k/Python")

#goal: loop through each URL, run BS,
#write to .txt named with matching CIK and date element

for index, url in enumerate(tuples):

    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(tuples)
    test = fp.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(test,"lxml")
    output=soup.get_text()
    file=open("url%s.txt","w",encoding='utf-8')
    file.close()
    file.write(output)
```

A couple of issues:

When I try to write the loop from the dataframe I get the following error:

**'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed**

I believe the answer here is to convert to a tuple, which I did. That makes it immutable. However now I am not sure how to refer to the different elements of the tuple when writing my loop.

The next step I attempted is to use enumerate to loop through the tuple. I am getting the following error for this:

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'.**

I believe this means the loop is trying to read the tuple in its entirety and not each element, but I am not sure and cannot find a good answer on the forums.

Finally, I am not sure how to reference elements of a tuple when writing each file to .txt. Right now I have url%s but that will just do URL1, URL2, etc.

Comment: `urllib.request.urlopen(tuples)` should probably be `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` I think?

Comment: tuples are indexed the same way as lists!

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you told us which lines these errors occurred on!